# how to fixe this expo app issues: 'boolean android.graphics.Path.isEmpty()' on a null object reference?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

Expo Go app on android keep throwing an error while on IOS nothing wrong happen.
The error I'm getting is as followed: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Path.isEmpty()' on a null object reference`
if anyone knows how I can wrap over this, I'll appreciate!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced this issue, for anyone still facing it, just make sure you are assigning a number to any props that have to do with dimensions not a 'null' value, replace null with 0 e.g) `width: hasImage ? 5 : 0` instead of `width: hasImage ? 5 : null`